# A0 - VM Instance - Is shared?

Tags: azure

**Hey guys,**

I have a virtual machine in Microsoft Azure Cloud platform.

The size is A0 which is the least configuration in the Azure environment.
[A0 Configuration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogvKP.png)

I was unable to take the SSH and also HTTP.

The CPU usage is also 100% sometimes.

Please let me know, Is the below configuration is enough to run applications ?.

I contacted support team, they are saying that the configuration for A0 is shared,

I don't understand which resource they are talking about as shared.

Disk, Network speed, memory.

Please explain

Regards,
Sathiya Moorthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A0 size is over-subscribed on the physical hardware. For this specific size only, **other customer deployments may impact the performance of your running workload.** The relative performance is outlined below as the expected baseline, subject to an approximate variability of 15 percent.

> I don't understand which resource they are talking about as shared.

In Azure, Basic A0 share **CPU core**.
[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.